# Call Microsoft Graph API using Graph SDK on behalf of flow

Tags: c#, .net, webapi, microsoft-graph-sdks

Any help here is greatly appreciated!

**Scenario**

I have a Vue web app that calls a .NET web API that I want to call the Microsoft Graph API with scope {user.read} using the On-Behalf-Of flow.

I am having trouble with acquiring the access token in this step while initializing the graph client:
`// This is the incoming token to exchange using on-behalf-of flow var oboToken = "JWT_TOKEN_TO_EXCHANGE";`

I have referenced Microsoft documentation for this but they are all accomplished through postman and REST api calls which doesn't apply to my scenario using the SDK.

Quite frankly, I don't understand how to configure Azure permissions for this scenario and how to programmatically acquire and exchange the access token with the Microsoft Graph API. Any help would be incredible!

Comment: please have a look at the code sample under Web API, ASP.NET "Sign in users and call MS Graph" using on-behalf-of flow here: https://shorturl.at/bmCEX

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I followed microsoft sdk documentation only to realize b2c authentication was not supported with the OBO flow

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).